# Pyomo attributes, methods, functions

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am new pyomo user. I want to learn that is there any document or way to see all attributes, methods and functions of pyomo? Same issue for CBC.

Comment: Please share with us what you have done so far. A minimum code example would be good.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question... if you have multiple questions... ask multiple questions!

Answer (score 2):

Source-level documentation is not currently supported for Pyomo.  The Pyomo developers have discussed whether/how to make this a priority, but this is not yet the focus of the team.

Answer (score 1):

From the interactive Python shell, you can import a module and then do a `help()` on it to see documentation included in the module itself:

```
>>> import pyomo
>>> help(pyomo)
```

You can also use the `dir()` command to see a list of all attributes and functions that are in the module:

```
>>> dir(pyomo)
```

But I have to ask -- what is wrong with the online documentation at [www.pyomo.org](http://www.pyomo.org)?  It seems like a very nice homepage for the project.

Comment: Web page and documents is enough for basic things. Write model and solve it. For example I want to write results to file, I am searching full document to find similar usage. And I find the answer here, therefore I think best way detailed documents like gurobi, cplex, gams or others.